# how to create a django migration for splitting model into multiple models

Tags: python, django

I have a django model that I am splitting into multiple models (django 1.9)
The app is more or less a system for tracking items and sets of items, which are usually associated with a file. (these files are not uploaded, or added by users, this is why I do no use the file field)

Here is a toy example of one of the items, which also has an associated file:

```
class ItemTypeA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    ...
    base_dir = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    rel_fname = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

In that model, I can filter on field1 and then get the appropriate file, (the real model has many fields, and relationships with other models not listed). There are also many more types of Items.

I want to move the file details another model with a onetoone relationship.

This might look like this:

```
class Filesystem(models.Model):
    dirpath = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    ... #Some other details for accessing the system, and system availablity.

class BaseFile(models.Model):
    filesystem = models.ForeignKey(Filesystem,related_name="system")
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    md5 = models.CharField(max_length=16, editable=False)
    md5_check_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    size = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="file_size")
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ItemTypeAFile(BaseFile):
    pass

class ItemTypeA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    file = models.OneToOneField(ItemTypeAFile)
```

I would like to create a migration for this such that filesystems are created when for each unique `base_dir==>dirpath`, and a new ItemTypeAFile object is created with `OldItemTypeA.rel_fname==>ItemTypeAFile.filepath`.

I do not really even know where to start with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the new model migration using south, then copy/create new objects for the new classes, then remove the fields from the original model.
Here's what I do:

1. Create the new model (ItemFile), DO NOT remove the fields from ItemA
2. Generate a south migration using the standard methods
3. Edit the migration, and add a loop that goes through all ItemA objects and creates the necessary Filesystem and ItemAFile objects.
4. Remove fields from the model, create another migration.

Here's what the code for (3) might look like:

```
def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    ItemA = apps.get_model("app", "ItemA")
    Filesystem = apps.get_model("app", "Filesystem")
    ItemAFile = apps.get_model("app", "ItemAFile")

    for item in ItemA.objects.all():
        fs,added = Filesystem.objects.get_or_create(dirpath=str(item.base_dir))
        itemafile=ItemAFile(itema=item, filesystem=fs, filepath=item.rel_fname)
        # do md5 stuff
        ....
        itemafile.save()

def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    Filesystem = apps.get_model("app", "Filesystem")
    ItemAFile = apps.get_model("app", "ItemAFile")

    Filesystem.objects.all().delete()
    ItemAFile.objects.all().delete()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        ...
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func),
    ]
```

I would consider putting the onetoone on the ItemAFile class rather than the ItemA class:

```
class ItemTypeAFile(BaseFile):
    item = models.OneToOneField(ItemTypeA)
```

This way if you delete an ItemA object, the associated ItemAFile object will be deleted as well. Since ItemAFile is an extension of ItemA, this might be the behavior you want.